# Upper limit to number of collaborators in Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just wanted some guidance on how many users can access a Google Sheet before it starts to slow down?

Let's say there are 10 sheets each with 10,000 cells, and the sheets contain functions using both Google Sheets and Apps Script.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is too broad. What does the functions does? How many formulas does your spreadsheet has? The users are viewers, "commenters" or editors? Are the users on the same location, let say a conference room or are they on different locations? ...

Comment: +1 @Ruben; there's also the question of whether the users are accessing concurrently or sequentially, in the same or different time zones, etc. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question to provide the information that may enable us to help. As a matter of interest, what is the maximum number of collaborators that you would like to have access to a Google spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm led to believe (but don't warrant) that the person who answered this 2017 question on Google Docs Help Forum  [Issues with document loading all the time and edits taking too long to populate](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/wOOTlzu0ZLQ;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/maxiumum$20number$20of$20editors) was a "Google employee" (whatever that may mean). I'm not certain that it throws much light on your question, except to reinforce the level of detail that you need to provide, including assumptions that you may be making, in order to answer your question.